Issues with Localization and addressables
I have been working on unity project with my team, one member merged feature with git and after the merge there are some issues with addressables; almost all localization tables are not marked as addressables, locaalization package created some groups of addressables and it seems like only those which are responsible for tables were changed. Analyze window and other things are demonstrated in images below. Team member didn't have localization and addressables package in git branch. It seems like I need to add assets to group that is somehow blocked. 
I asked GPT but it answerd just to mark them as addressables and add them to group, but it didn't know to which group do I need to adde them.

Check the console. Perhaps there is a git conflict in the package manifest or something like that.
